# Equivalent to SQL "Group By" statement

Tags: linq

I am working within Sage 200 Workspace designer and have come into a scenario where I have created the ideal query for a workspace for a client, but the problem is there are duplicate results because there is no group by statement (like the ones in SQL).

```
int EMPTY_YEAR = 1899;
var q = from wo in cxt.vw_WorksOrderses                                      
join bomr in cxt.BomRecords on wo.BomReference equals bomr.Reference 
into wonUniqueOrders where wonUniqueOrders.Count() == 0 where wo.Status 
!= "Completed" && wo.Status != "Closed" && wo.Status != "Cancelled"
select new
{
}
return q;
```

Not too sure how to write the GroupBy statement in this sort of Linq query, as the way I use it in Sage 200 seems very different compared to the way others are producing Linq code.

Any help?

Thank you all.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I had to create a new Sage addon in order to write to connect the models, so it won't be as easy as copy pasting the query for testing purposes.

Comment: What happens if you use the regular GroupBy as everybody else?

Comment: The thing is, the way i'm writing the Linq query is different, I understand how they write it in vb or c#, but in terms of incorporating it into my Sage query, I cannot figure out how to write it here. There are plenty of articles about the GroupBy statement, but none that are being used in Sage 200 like this one :(

Comment: Can you just add a `.Distinct()` around the query? Also, wouldn't the `where wo.`* conditions be better off before the join?

Comment: That's what i'm sort of edging towards, I don't know how /where to add these as it seems like i've been writing Linq code completely different to other people! Not at all sure where I would add ".Distinct()" to, and not even sure if it would work when i'm writing it like this, i've been stuck on this for a while. Also, not sure about the wo. conditions, it works either way, but could try it. Completely stuck!